# How do you pass an array into Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra

I have this in my rspec test

```
it 'that can be mass inserted' do
        score_count = Score.all.length
        post '/score', @mass_score_data
        Score.all.length.should eq score_count+2
end
```

where @mass_score_data is an array of hashes [{id: 5, something: 3}, {id: 4, something: 2}]. I'm assuming that I am getting this array from an app that connects to Sinatra.

rspec says

```
 Failure/Error: post '/score', @mass_score_data
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `read' for #<Array:0x007fd7e507bd80>
```

Am I missing something here, or can we just not pass arrays into Sinatra? BTW I also tried arrays like [1, 2, 3, 4], it still is "undefined method 'read'"

Comment: Are you trying to make multiple `post` requests, or just one? =/

Comment: @Ajedi32 one post request, the parameter to be passed in is an array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your `post` body in the `Score` class looks like:

```
post '/add_scores' do
  scores = params[:scores]
  ....
end
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
post 'add_scores', {:scores => @mass_data}
```

Look at [Testing in Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Testing) for further reading.

Comment: If that is the case, do I have to change how the data is passed from the front-end? Instead of sending [{}, {}], I should probably send {scores: [{}, {}]}

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to do that, as long as the data in the form is called scores,

Comment: Thanks. What I did is to make those with multiple data have a data: attribute which I pass in. Then I handle arrays differently by doing an each |item| block